# r OpenMP crashes

Tags: r, openmp

I'm having trouble with openMP crashes. Here's a simple example

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)

dt1 <- data.table(replicate(5,sample(0:100,50,rep=TRUE)))
dt2 <- data.table(replicate(5,sample(0:100,50,rep=TRUE)))
dtList <- c("dt1", "dt2")
dtList <- mget(dtList)
mergedDT <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE), dtList)
```

In RStudio, I get no information other than the crash. But when I run my code in a shell, I get a message like the following. I think the problem is that one or more of my other loaded packages initializes OMP, perhaps with a different version.

I have copied the list of packages being loaded, version numbers as comments. But in particular when installing caret there were a lot of dependencies, which I compiled locally, which I suppose could be causing the problem.

My specific question is what process do I use to diagnose the offending package(s) and what to do when I find them.

> OMP: Error #15: Initializing libomp.dylib, but found libomp.dylib
>   already initialized. OMP: Hint: This means that multiple copies of the
>   OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous,
>   since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best
>   thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked
>   into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP
>   runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented
>   workaround you can set the environment variable
>   KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute,
>   but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For
>   more information, please see
>   http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/. Abort trap: 6

```
library(data.table) # 1.10.5
library(ggplot2) # 2.2.1.9000
library(lattice) # 0.20-35
library(caret) # 6.0-78
```

I'm using a Mac, OS 10.13.2. R is at 3.4.2.

I have installed openMP as part of llvm (I think). When I `type brew info llvm` in a shell, it returns 
llvm: stable 5.0.1

Comment: Try `Sys.setenv(KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE)` before loading the packages.